# SQL Server Encryption via symmetric keys (AES_256)

Tags: .net, sql-server, encryption, aes, database-security

I was reading about encryption in database (SQL Server) and came across an MS article(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/encrypt-a-column-of-data?view=sql-server-2017)

In the article, they created a master key, then created a certificate via that using AES_256 algorithm and then encrypted/decrypted the data via above certificate.

But as long as both keys & certificates are there in same database server, anyone who gets access to the server can always decrypt the data. Then where is the security? I might not understood it properly so posted this here to get proper idea to use encryption at database side and protect keys.

I followed below queries.

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY  PASSWORD = '<some strong password>';
Go 

CREATE CERTIFICATE Sales09  
   WITH SUBJECT = 'Customer Credit Card Numbers';  
GO  

CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY CreditCards_Key11  
    WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256  
    ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Sales09;  
GO  

-- Create a column in which to store the encrypted data.  
ALTER TABLE Sales.CreditCard   
    ADD CardNumber_Encrypted varbinary(128);   
GO  

-- Open the symmetric key with which to encrypt the data.  
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY CreditCards_Key11  
   DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Sales09;  

-- Encrypt the value in column CardNumber using the  
-- symmetric key CreditCards_Key11.  
-- Save the result in column CardNumber_Encrypted.    
UPDATE Sales.CreditCard  
SET CardNumber_Encrypted = EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('CreditCards_Key11')  
    , CardNumber, 1, HashBytes('SHA1', CONVERT( varbinary  
    , CreditCardID)));  
GO  

-- Verify the encryption.  
-- First, open the symmetric key with which to decrypt the data.  

OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY CreditCards_Key11  
   DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Sales09;  
GO  

-- Now list the original card number, the encrypted card number,  
-- and the decrypted ciphertext. If the decryption worked,  
-- the original number will match the decrypted number.  

SELECT CardNumber, CardNumber_Encrypted   
    AS 'Encrypted card number', CONVERT(nvarchar,  
    DecryptByKey(CardNumber_Encrypted, 1 ,   
    HashBytes('SHA1', CONVERT(varbinary, CreditCardID))))  
    AS 'Decrypted card number' FROM Sales.CreditCard;  
GO
```

Comment: One who has raised close request, please provide some information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having a discussion with microsoft people, i got below article which fulfills my need.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017#how-it-works

Ref: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/2673